# What does the に in 数値を見るに mean?

Tags: particle-に

『なるほど。数値を見る**に**、一時的に顕在化した力は経路を通して再封印されたみたいだけどーー早めに機嫌を直しておいた方がよさそうね』

Hi. What does the に mean here? I would expect 見ると.
Thank you.